# Difference of two collections

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm trying to get a difference of two collections however every time getting below exception. Kindly help. My sample code is also available below. Not sure what's going wrong here... can `MULTISET EXCEPT` not be applied on `RECORD` types?

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'

```
DECLARE
   TYPE FRND_OBJ IS RECORD
   (
      FrndID      NUMBER,
      JOBID       NUMBER,
      REGIONID    NUMBER,
      COLLEGEID   NUMBER
   );

   TYPE FRND_LIST IS TABLE OF FRND_OBJ;

   CURSOR c_date_rolling
   IS
      SELECT 1,
             2,
             3,
             4
        FROM DUAL;

   lv_roll_date         FRND_LIST;
   lv_roll_date_full    FRND_LIST;
   lv_roll_date_delta   FRND_LIST;
   g_error_msg          VARCHAR2 (1500);
BEGIN
   SELECT 5,
          6,
          7,
          8
     BULK COLLECT INTO lv_roll_date_full
     FROM DUAL;

   OPEN c_date_rolling;

   FETCH c_date_rolling BULK COLLECT INTO lv_roll_date;

   CLOSE c_date_rolling;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Full Count: ' || lv_roll_date_full.COUNT);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Rolling Count: ' || lv_roll_date.COUNT);
   lv_roll_date_delta := lv_roll_date_full MULTISET EXCEPT lv_roll_date;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (lv_roll_date_delta.COUNT);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      g_error_msg :=
            SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200)
         || SUBSTR (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, 20);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (g_error_msg);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      g_error_msg :=
            SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200)
         || SUBSTR (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, 20);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (g_error_msg);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2539162?tstart=0) is explained, that you will need a MAP or ORDER method. In your sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE frnd_obj
   AUTHID DEFINER AS OBJECT
(
   frndid NUMBER,
   jobid NUMBER,
   regionid NUMBER,
   collegeid NUMBER,
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION tostring
      RETURN VARCHAR2
)
/

SHOW ERRORS;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY frnd_obj AS
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION tostring
      RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN TO_CHAR (frndid) || ';' || TO_CHAR (jobid) || ';' || TO_CHAR (regionid) || ';' || TO_CHAR (collegeid);
   END tostring;
END;
/

CREATE TYPE FRND_LIST IS TABLE OF FRND_OBJ;
```

And now you can use it:

```
DECLARE
--   TYPE FRND_OBJ IS RECORD
--   (
--      FrndID      NUMBER,
--      JOBID       NUMBER,
--      REGIONID    NUMBER,
--      COLLEGEID   NUMBER
--   );

--   TYPE FRND_LIST IS TABLE OF FRND_OBJ;

   CURSOR c_date_rolling
   IS
      SELECT FRND_OBJ(1,
             2,
             3,
             4)
        FROM DUAL; 
--        union all
--      SELECT FRND_OBJ(5,
--          6,
--          7,
--          8)
--        FROM DUAL;

   lv_roll_date         FRND_LIST;
   lv_roll_date_full    FRND_LIST;
   lv_roll_date_delta   FRND_LIST;
   g_error_msg          VARCHAR2 (1500);
BEGIN
   SELECT FRND_OBJ(5,
          6,
          7,
          8)
     BULK COLLECT INTO lv_roll_date_full
     FROM DUAL;

   OPEN c_date_rolling;

   FETCH c_date_rolling BULK COLLECT INTO lv_roll_date;

   CLOSE c_date_rolling;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Full Count: ' || lv_roll_date_full.COUNT);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Rolling Count: ' || lv_roll_date.COUNT);
   lv_roll_date_delta := lv_roll_date_full MULTISET EXCEPT ALL lv_roll_date;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (lv_roll_date_delta.COUNT);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      g_error_msg :=
            SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200)
         || SUBSTR (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, 20);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (g_error_msg);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      g_error_msg :=
            SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200)
         || SUBSTR (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, 20);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (g_error_msg);
END;
/
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 15 seconds *8-) A slight extension to answer the actual posed question: no, you can't use record types, because they can't have map/order methods. You can also use an object type which doesn't have map/order, but then you have to `select multiset ... into ... from dual`. And you can't use record types in SQL, so that still requires an object type. But `FRND_LIST` can be a PL/SQL table type - it works either way.

Comment: thanks to both of you, learned something new about the objects. The HERE link shared by @Mottor was very insightful!